# My iPad won't turn on even though it has charge

Tags: ipad, battery, screen, charging

my ipad 2 won't turn on after i dropped it. it had 93% charge and is still on charge but won't turn on. i have pressed the power button, home button and both at the same time. i don't have a iTunes account. and if i press both buttons i can hear it making a screenshot. the screen is navy blue, not black, so i know it is on, but not showing any display. if i try to restart it, there is no apple logo, just blue. what should i do?

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hardware issue. You need to go to the Apple store as you have already tried hard rest .
you can follow this guide also :-

> https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/161982/ipad+2+-+My+screen+is+blue+after+falling.